# Convert sha512 to md5

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5, sha512

Use SHA512 as encryption in Multicraft panel (which you can change the settings for MD5), but I need to use an older version of the same database. This old version did not have the option to encrypt with SHA512, but only with MD5. Thus, all passwords are invalid with MD5.

It's possible convert all SHA512 passwords in MySQL database to MD5?

Comment: See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [Modern, Secure, Salted Password Hashing Made Simple](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes)
It is the users who are at risk from poor password handling, they expect and deserve good security.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted so badly. I wouldn't advise doing what the OP is trying to do, but IMO it's a valid question that is on-topic and clearly answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHA512 and MD5 are [hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), not encryption algorithms. By design, they are not reversible.

The only way to convert these values is to wait for each user to log in, validate their password against the existing SHA512 hash, and rehash¹ their input with MD5. This is the reverse of how password hashes are updated to more secure standards.

**But please, *please*, don't do this.** [MD5 is hopelessly broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). You would be doing your users a *huge* disservice to revert from SHA512 to MD5. Find a way to use the newer version of your software.

---

¹As noted by zaph in a comment, "rehashing" is an oversimplification, and depending on how your panel is actually implemented it might be using insecure password storage today.

To provide reasonable security each password must also have a unique random [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) (which protects against things like [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)) and each hash must be iterated enough times to make [brute forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) impractical. As computers get more powerful the number of iterations must be increased. Today it is common to iterate tens or hundreds of thousands of times.

Cryptography is *shockingly* difficult to get right. Instead of trying to follow all the best practices manually, use libraries and functions that operate at the right level of abstraction and have been audited for security. An algorithm like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (via PHP's built-in [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, where it is currently the default algorithm) would be a good choice.

Comment: SHA-512 does still does not provide acceptable security, the additional security is minimal. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph, of course. But the OP isn't asking how to implement password hashes securely. The question is whether existing SHA512-based hashes can be converted to MD5-based hashes for use with a third-party program. The practical answer is no. I certainly hope that the software being used is implemented correctly using a well-chosen algorithm from a publicly-audited library, but if it boils down to a settings change in a graphical panel I'm not sure that these details are relevant. In any case, I've upvoted your comments and will add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

By design, both MD5 and SHA512 are *one-way* hashes. In order to convert SHA512 to MD5, you would need to know *both* the original password for every password your are trying to convert, and *also* the salt that was used to encrypt them. You almost certainly wouldn't know every password for every one of your users.

One-way hashes work by actually casting the same algorithm every time a user logs in. The user types in their password, the algorithm is applied to it, and if it perfectly matches the copy in the database that has already been hashed, then the user is logged in. You can't use any sort of algorithm to work out what the original password was, only to compare if the output of applying a specific password would be to a password that is already encrypted.

MD5 is also a far *weaker* hashing algorithm than SHA512. Converting to MD5 would make your password *far* less secure, and this would be something that you probably wouldn't want to do. Instead, you should be looking at a way to incorporate the new database system.

Comment: 1.5 times longer in execution is not "far less secure", I just ran some benchmarks  in a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 laptop. Password hashes are broken by running lists go frequently used passwords, SHA-512 will cause the attacker to spend an extra 50% longer. Sure SHA-512 is a better hash function but in this usage that is not important. See the comment to @Chris for details on how passwords should be handled.